# Saving date form to ruby variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a date range form in my rails app, so the user can input two dates, and these dates will post to a query to return results from an API the application is connected to.

My model looks like this: It allows the first date and second date to default to create last week's date range, but it is supposed to accept options to overwrite the default...

```
class Day
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Conversion
extend ActiveModel::Naming

attr_accessor :first_day, :second_day

def initialize(attributes = {})
  attributes.each do |name, value|
    send("#{name}=", value)
  end
end

def self.monday(options = {})
  if options[:first_day]
    return Date.parse(options[:first_day])
  else
    d = Date.today
    seven_days_ago = (d - 7)
    seven_days_ago.beginning_of_week
  end
end

#defines the end of last week for the query
def self.sunday(options = {})
  if options[:second_day]
    return Date.parse(options[:second_day])
  else
    d = Date.today
    seven_days_ago = (d - 7)
    seven_days_ago.end_of_week
  end
end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @day do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Beginning Date' %>
    <%= f.datepicker :first_day, :size => 6 %>
    <%= f.label 'End Date' %>
    <%= f.datepicker :second_day, :size => 6 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And controller:

```
def new
  @day = Day.new
end

# POST /days
# POST /days.json
def create
  @day = Day.new(params[:day])
  if @day.valid?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

I am currently accessing the Day.monday and Day.sunday methods in queries that live in some of my controllers.  These values always end up being the default, even if the user posts other dates through the form (the idea is to overwrite the default values).

I would prefer a javascript option - the user inputs two dates, they stick to the methods without refreshing, then when the dates are reset it goes back to default.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I recommend you call your model something other than `Day` since `Day.first_day` doesn't really make that much sense. Perhaps `DateRange`?

Comment: Also use `DateTime` instead of `Date` just in case you ever have to do any localisation in the future.